# react 15.5.4 enzyme shallow and mount are not working

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, enzyme

I'm trying to test my `<Header />` component, but it seems that `shallow` and `mount` are not working. I read that in [react v15.5.0](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2017/04/07/react-v15.5.0.html) there are some updates, but I didn't understand how to make my tests work.

I'm using `"react": "^15.5.4",` and `"enzyme": "^2.9.1",`. If `shallow` or `mount` are not called, everything works. It was also tried installing `"react-test-renderer": "^15.6.1",`.

```
import React from 'react';
import { expect } from 'chai';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import Header from '../../../components/header/Header';

describe('<Header />', () => {
  it('should be correct', () => {
    const props = {
      attendant: {
        id: 1,
        first_name: 'firstName',
        last_name: 'lastName',
      },
    };

    const wrapper = shallow(<Header {...props} />);
    console.log(wrapper);
    expect(0).eql(0);
  });
});
```

Log error:

```
Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in.
/Users/gtmiyabe/Documents/contactto-master-frontend/node_modules/react-test-renderer/lib/shallow/ReactCompositeComponent.js:305
        return Component(publicProps, publicContext, updateQueue);
               ^

TypeError: Component is not a function
    at /Users/gtmiyabe/Documents/contactto-master-frontend/node_modules/react-test-renderer/lib/shallow/ReactCompositeComponent.js:305:16
    at measureLifeCyclePerf (/Users/gtmiyabe/Documents/contactto-master-frontend/node_modules/react-test-renderer/lib/shallow/ReactCompositeComponent.js:75:12)
    at ShallowComponentWrapper._constructComponentWithoutOwner (/Users/gtmiyabe/Documents/contactto-master-frontend/node_modules/react-test-renderer/lib/shallow/ReactCompositeComponent.js:304:14)
    at ShallowComponentWrapper.mountComponent (/Users/gtmiyabe/Documents/contactto-master-frontend/node_modules/react-test-renderer/lib/shallow/ReactCompositeComponent.js:187:21)
    at Object.mountComponent (/Users/gtmiyabe/Documents/contactto-master-frontend/node_modules/react-test-renderer/lib/shallow/ReactReconciler.js:45:35)
    at ReactShallowRenderer._render (/Users/gtmiyabe/Documents/contactto-master-frontend/node_modules/react-test-renderer/lib/shallow/ReactShallowRenderer.js:138:23)
    at _batchedRender (/Users/gtmiyabe/Documents/contactto-master-frontend/node_modules/react-test-renderer/lib/shallow/ReactShallowRenderer.js:85:12)
    at Object.batchedUpdates (/Users/gtmiyabe/Documents/contactto-master-frontend/node_modules/react-test-renderer/lib/shallow/ReactDefaultBatchingStrategy.js:60:14)
    at Object.batchedUpdates (/Users/gtmiyabe/Documents/contactto-master-frontend/node_modules/react-test-renderer/lib/shallow/ReactUpdates.js:97:27)
    at ReactShallowRenderer.render (/Users/gtmiyabe/Documents/contactto-master-frontend/node_modules/react-test-renderer/lib/shallow/ReactShallowRenderer.js:112:18)
    at ReactShallowRenderer.render (/Users/gtmiyabe/Documents/contactto-master-frontend/node_modules/enzyme/build/react-compat.js:171:37)
    at /Users/gtmiyabe/Documents/contactto-master-frontend/node_modules/enzyme/build/ShallowWrapper.js:128:26
    at ReactDefaultBatchingStrategyTransaction.perform (/Users/gtmiyabe/Documents/contactto-master-frontend/node_modules/react-test-renderer/lib/shallow/Transaction.js:143:20)
    at Object.batchedUpdates (/Users/gtmiyabe/Documents/contactto-master-frontend/node_modules/react-test-renderer/lib/shallow/ReactDefaultBatchingStrategy.js:62:26)
    at Object.batchedUpdates (/Users/gtmiyabe/Documents/contactto-master-frontend/node_modules/react-test-renderer/lib/shallow/ReactUpdates.js:97:27)
    at ReactShallowRenderer.unstable_batchedUpdates (/Users/gtmiyabe/Documents/contactto-master-frontend/node_modules/react-test-renderer/lib/shallow/ReactShallowRenderer.js:130:25)
    at performBatchedUpdates (/Users/gtmiyabe/Documents/contactto-master-frontend/node_modules/enzyme/build/ShallowWrapper.js:103:21)
    at /Users/gtmiyabe/Documents/contactto-master-frontend/node_modules/enzyme/build/ShallowWrapper.js:127:9
    at withSetStateAllowed (/Users/gtmiyabe/Documents/contactto-master-frontend/node_modules/enzyme/build/Utils.js:284:3)
    at new ShallowWrapper (/Users/gtmiyabe/Documents/contactto-master-frontend/node_modules/enzyme/build/ShallowWrapper.js:126:38)
    at shallow (/Users/gtmiyabe/Documents/contactto-master-frontend/node_modules/enzyme/build/shallow.js:19:10)
    at Suite.<anonymous> (/Users/gtmiyabe/Documents/contactto-master-frontend/app/test/components/header/Header.test.js:17:21)
    at Object.create (/Users/gtmiyabe/Documents/contactto-master-frontend/node_modules/mocha/lib/interfaces/common.js:114:19)
    at context.describe.context.context (/Users/gtmiyabe/Documents/contactto-master-frontend/node_modules/mocha/lib/interfaces/bdd.js:44:27)
    at Suite.<anonymous> (/Users/gtmiyabe/Documents/contactto-master-frontend/app/test/components/header/Header.test.js:7:3)
    at Object.create (/Users/gtmiyabe/Documents/contactto-master-frontend/node_modules/mocha/lib/interfaces/common.js:114:19)
    at context.describe.context.context (/Users/gtmiyabe/Documents/contactto-master-frontend/node_modules/mocha/lib/interfaces/bdd.js:44:27)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/gtmiyabe/Documents/contactto-master-frontend/app/test/components/header/Header.test.js:6:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
    at loader (/Users/gtmiyabe/Documents/contactto-master-frontend/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:144:5)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/Users/gtmiyabe/Documents/contactto-master-frontend/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:154:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:513:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at /Users/gtmiyabe/Documents/contactto-master-frontend/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:230:27
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Mocha.loadFiles (/Users/gtmiyabe/Documents/contactto-master-frontend/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:227:14)
    at Mocha.run (/Users/gtmiyabe/Documents/contactto-master-frontend/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:495:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/gtmiyabe/Documents/contactto-master-frontend/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha:469:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:605:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:158:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:575:3
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! contactto-master@1.0.0 test: `mocha --require ignore-styles --require mock-local-storage ./testSetup.js "./app/test/**/*.test.js"`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the contactto-master@1.0.0 test script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/gtmiyabe/.npm/_logs/2017-07-11T18_45_30_025Z-debug.log
```

Header:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import style from './Header.scss';
import User from '../user/User';

const Header = ({ attendant }) => (
  <div className={style.wrapper}>
    <header />
    {attendant &&
      <User
        attendant={attendant}
      />
    }
  </div>
);

Header.propTypes = {
  attendant: PropTypes.shape({
    id: PropTypes.number,
    first_name: PropTypes.string,
    last_name: PropTypes.string,
  }).isRequired,
};

export default Header;
```

Comment: Please paste here error message, right now it is hard to say what is wrong.

Comment: Ok, the log message error (this is the first part, I'll post the whole log in my question): Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in.

Comment: Can you paste contents of  `Header` file? Mainly how do you export it? It looks like component is exported in a wrong way.

Comment: Yes, I posted it now. I saw this message, but I checked and tried doing with another ways, but all failed.

Comment: I have the same error only when I pass invalid component to the shallow or mount functions. It looks like Header in your test is not a valid react component. You can debug and check the type of Header variable in your test. Based on the code you provided, the only missing thing that I found is instrumenting mocha for using babel (see my answer). You could create a reproducible git repository because without it's hard to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to render invalid react component. Hard to say why but it looks like `Header` variable is not a valid react component. Your code looks okay and tests should work so it looks like problem is with importing / exporting.

You can try this just for a test

```
describe('<Header />', () => {
  describe('should be correct', () => {
    const props = {
      attendant: {
        id: 1,
        first_name: 'firstName',
        last_name: 'lastName',
      },
    };

    const wrapper = shallow(<Header.default {...props} />); // Header is an object so probably it has default property...
    console.log(wrapper);
    expect(0).eql(0);
  });
});
```

1. Install missing dependency in case if it's not installed already

   ```
   npm install --save babel-core
   ```
2. Change command `test` in `package.json`

   ```
   test: `mocha --require ignore-styles --require mock-local-storage ./testSetup.js "./app/test/**/*.test.js"`
   ```

   to

   ```
   test: `mocha —-compilers js:babel-core/register --require ignore-styles --require mock-local-storage ./testSetup.js "./app/test/**/*.test.js"`
   ```

I think you've forgotten about instrumenting `mocha` to use `babel`.

Comment: Thank you by the response, but the error persists :(

Comment: A part of the error is: TypeError: Cannot read property 'contextTypes' of undefined  at ShallowComponentWrapper._maskContext (/Users/gtmiyabe/Documents/contactto-master-frontend/node_modules/react-test-renderer/lib/shallow/ReactCompositeComponent.js:460:33)

Comment: `mocha` was using `babel` at my component `testSetup.js` `require('babel-register')();`

Comment: I'm curious, what's the output of `console.log(typeof Header, typeof Header.default, Header, Header.default)`

Comment: The output is: object undefined {} undefined

Comment: Does this problem still exist if you try this: `const wrapper = shallow(<Header />);` I'm thinking maybe `<User />` component is messed up so try shallow render only for static and "safe" component, even like: `shallow(<div>Test</div>)`.

Comment: I removed the component `<User />`, but the error persists with the same message. I also tried testing only the `<User />` component and it failed too. I perceived that when `shallow` is removed it works fine.

Comment: I tried `const wrapper = shallow(<div>Test</div>);` and it works. But I still don't know where is the error.

Comment: It must be something with importing / exporting. Can you paste output of `console.log(JSON.stringify(Header, undefined, 2))` because I just want to be 100% sure that `Header` is real React component.

One thing which came to my mind is also just for test, you can try and add `transform-es2015-modules-commonjs` to `.babelrc` to `plugins: []`. Remember about installing this transform by `npm install babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs --save-dev`

Comment: Ok, the output is: `{}`, I installed this but nothing happened.

Comment: I made the repository https://github.com/hinok/react-mocha-enzyme which contains only required elements to run mocha tests with enzyme. Tests are working so you can compare with your project and try to find the root of the problem. I hope that at least it will help you.

Comment: The big problem (`import Header from '../../../components/header/Header';`) was that in the same `header` folder I had `Header.jsx` and `Header.scss`.